# minnaert correction

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, remote-sensing

I want to apply minnaert topographic correction, for all scenes over roi by computing coefficients?

Method: minnaert
ref_c = ref_o * (cos_z / cos_i) ^k
where, k is obtained by linear regression of
ln(ref_o) = ln(ref_c) - k ln(cos_i/cos_z)

Here is code for single image.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/861f3afd010ffebb4929bef3ec9996e9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply wrap the code you have into a function and map over your image collection, invoking the function for each image.

```
var correctedCollection = collection.map(minnaert)

function minnaert(img) {
  // The minnaert code, returning the resulting image
}
```

Here's a concrete example showing the yearly median corrected and uncorrected. (I tried to use it with L8. mind that I don't know if the coefficients are the same):

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d5e5c78672361ae320290310ec87156d

Comment: The correction code uses azimuth and zenith properties for Landsat imagery. They have different property names for Sentinel 2. I also removed the division by 10000.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a39da6fb42d515e91b32d7131f481f99